# Delphi: EnumPrinterData example

Tags: delphi, printing, spooler

Can you please provide an example of using EnumPrinterData function in Delphi to get a list of printers in system?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a simple list of installed printers, you don't need `EnumPrinterData`. You can use `TPrinter.Printers` property:

```
for I := 0 to Printer.Printers.Count - 1 do
  Writeln(Printer.Printers[I]);
```

Comment: Correct. The EnumPrinterData function enumerates configuration data for a specified printer.

Comment: I need some function to check if the spoolsv service is not hanging. Is enumerating Printers collection good for this?

Comment: I'm not sure, perhaps you could use QueryServiceStatus.